# Store output from RABL as ActiveRecord attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I need to store a JSON object as an ActiveRecord attribute after rendered using a RABL template. How can I do this?

A simple example would be

```
MyModel.my_data = <output from the RABL template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#rendering-templates-directly

```
Rabl::Renderer.json(@model, 'model/show')
```

which should do the trick.

Comment: I gets the following error message "uninitialized constant Rabl::Renderer" What might be the cause?

Comment: What version of RABL are you using? What version of Rails?

Comment: "uninitialized constant Rabl::Renderer" occures for earlier versions of rabl gem. I tried with version 1.7 and it worked.